# AutoCompleteTextView wont work as EditText did

Tags: java, android, autocomplete, autocompletetextview

I replaced an EditText with an AutoCompleteTextView in my app to make things a little more user friendly, but I am having an error.

In the app, the user types in the name of a plant, and then clicks a button to be taken to a new activity where some information about the plant is displayed.

**The error: the app crashes after I press the button to be taken to the next activity after the user types in the name of the plant. This didnt happen when I still had an EditText. Perhaps I am using the AutoCompleteTextView wrong?**

Heres the relevant code:

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

AutoCompleteTextView edit;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    //this is the AutoComplete
    AutoCompleteTextView edit = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.et_item);

    //this is the list of suggestions for the AutoComplete
    String[] items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.items_array);
    java.util.Arrays.sort(items);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
    edit.setAdapter(adapter);

//this is the method that is called when the button is pressed
public void find(View view) {

    String name = edit.getText().toString();

    //basically, whatever is typed into the AutoComplete is turned into a string, and 
    //if the string matches one of the existing plants, the user is taken to 
    //the next activity

    if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("Sunflower")){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Sunflower.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("Cactus")){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Cactus.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Can anyone see why this does not work?

Answer (score 2):

Change below:

```
 AutoCompleteTextView edit = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.et_item);
```

To:

```
 edit = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.et_item);
```

Your autocomplete textview scope is limited to `onCreate()` and

> edit.getText().toString();

You are trying to get text from it which is not initialized yet. So it will get null pointer exception.

Comment: Youre a great help! Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped.